# Expired password change fails

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jtopen

I am using JTOpen API to access an AS400 system.

I can successfully change an active AS400 user password like this:

```
AS400 system = new AS400("AS400SYSTEM", "AS400USER");
system.changePassword("OLDPASSWORD", "NEWPASSWORD");
```

On the other hand, when I try to change an expired user password in the same way I get the following exception thrown from the 2nd line:

> com.ibm.as400.access.AS400SecurityException: Password is incorrect.

What do I need to do first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the user was not disabled (enabled then :P) only the password was expired.

As it turned out the problem was that the first character of the new password was numeric. AS400 console doesn't like that at all...

http://search400.techtarget.com/answer/Setting-iSeries-passwords

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Is the password expired or is the user profile disabled?

If the profile is disabled, it can't log on at all ... since you can't log on, you can't change the password.

Try invoking the connect(AS400.SIGNON) method before changing the password.

If all else fails, try activating a [trace](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/Trace.html) to see what the system is trying to do under the covers.